# Checkbox .change() event doesn't fire, when "fired" by another checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm using a checkbox to check all other checkboxes in a table.
After a checkbox being checked INSIDE the table (on change) I sum up every textbox value in the same tr.
**It works well on Firefox and Chrome.**
On IE11 and below (it's important for me that it works in EVERY browser) the first change of the "all" checkbox just tick the others, but doesn't sum up the textbox values.
On the second click he sums up but untick the checkboxes.
So it works in the wrong way because the first "change" is ignored or sth.

Sorry for my bad english and bad description.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Auswahl <input type="checkbox" id="allcheck" /></th>
        <th>Kunden-Nr.</th>
        <th>Personal-Nr.</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gutscheintyp</th>
        <th>Betrag €</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="check" /></td>
        <td align="left">1</td>
        <td align="left">2</td>
        <td align="left">3</td>
        <td align="left">4</td>
        <td align="left" class="typ">5</td>
        <td align="center" class="texttd">
        <input type="text" class="txt" maxlength="5" onclick="this.select()" value="20.00" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5"></th>
            <th colspan="1"">Summe</th>
            <th colspan="1" id="sum">0,00</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

allcheck is the id of the checkbox, checking all others. :)

```
// TICK ALL CHECKBOXES
$('#allcheck').click (function () {
    var checkedStatus = this.checked;
    $('table tbody').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
    });
});



// SUM UP TEXTBOXES IF CHECKBOX CHECKED
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var sum = 0.00;
    $("table tr td input:checked").each(function(){
        test = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val();
        test = test.replace( ",",".");
    if (isNaN(test)) {
        sum = 0.00;
    }
        sum += parseFloat(test, 10);
    $("#sum").html(sum.toString().replace(".",","));
});
    sum = parseFloat(sum, 10);
    sum = sum.toFixed(2);
    $("#sum").html(sum.toString().replace(".",","));
});
```

I hope these information are enough for you to help me a little. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that changing "checked" property does not always trigger "change" event.

So you must move your sum calculation into separate function and call it explicitly in "#allcheck" click handler

(also cleaned your code a bit)

```
// TICK ALL CHECKBOXES
$('#allcheck').click (function () {
    var checkedStatus = this.checked;
    $('table tbody').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);        
    });
    updateSum();
});

// SUM UP TEXTBOXES IF CHECKBOX CHECKED
$('tbody input[type="checkbox"]').change(updateSum);

function updateSum() {
    var sum = 0.00;
    $("tbody input:checked").each(function(){
        var test = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val();
        var testNum = parseFloat(test.replace( ",", "."));
        if (!isNaN(testNum)) {
            sum += testNum;
        }        
    });    
    $("#sum").text(sum.toFixed(2).replace(".",","));
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y779R/1/)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `click` event use `change` event for all check checbox. on change will fire after changing to new value and `this.checked` will give you correct value :

```
$('#allcheck').change(function() {
    var checkedStatus = this.checked;
    $('table tbody').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
    });
});
```

Comment: try changing `$('#allcheck').change(function() {` to `$('#allcheck').on("change",function() {`

Comment: Same thing. Still "ignores" the first change in sum up.
And now it doesn't sum up in firefox and chrome, too.